# Brezis's Ex 3.32: projection on the domain of a proper convex l.s.c. map

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, projection

I'm doing Ex 3.32.(5. and 6.) in Brezis's book of *Functional Analysis*. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a uniformly convex Banach space and $C \subset E$ a nonempty.
>
> 1. Prove that for every $x \in E$,
>    $$
>    \inf _{y \in C}|x-y|
>    $$
>    is achieved by some unique point in $C$, denoted by $P x$.
> 2. Prove that every minimizing sequence $\left(y_{n}\right)$ in $C$ converges strongly to $P x$.
> 3. Prove that the map $x \mapsto P x$ is continuous from $E$ strong into $E$ strong.
> 4. More precisely, prove that $P$ is uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $E$.
>
> Let $\varphi: E \rightarrow(-\infty,+\infty]$ be a convex l.s.c. function, $\varphi \not \equiv+\infty$.
>
> 5. Prove that for every $x \in E$ and every integer $n \geq 1$,
>    $$
>    \inf _{y \in E}\left\{n|x-y|^{2}+\varphi(y)\right\}
>    $$
>    is achieved at some unique point, denoted by $y_{n}$.
> 6. Prove that $y_{n} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} P x$, where $C=\overline{D(\varphi)}$.

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5. 

Fix $x\in E$ and let $(y_m)$ be a sequence that minimizes $n|x-y|^{2}+\varphi(y)$. Because $\varphi$ is proper l.s.c. convex, it is bounded from below by a continuous affine function. It follows that $(y_m)$ is bounded. On the other hand, $n|x-y|^{2}+\varphi(y)$ is convex and l.s.c. in norm topology, so it is in weak topology. Also, bounded convex set is weakly compact in reflexive space. Because $E$ is uniformly convex, it is reflexive. It follows that the minimizer indeed exists. Uniformly convex space is strictly convex, i.e., $y \mapsto |y|^2$ is strictly convex, so the minimizer is unique.

6.

We fix $x\in E$ and consider $f_n (y) : = n|x-y|^2 +\varphi(y)$. Then $f_n(y_n) \le f_n(y)$ for all $y\in E$ and $n \ge 1$. In particular, $f_{n+1}(y_{n+1}) \le f_{n+1}(y_n)$ and $f_{n}(y_{n}) \le f_{n}(y_{n+1})$, i.e.,
$$
\begin{cases}
(n+1)|x-y_{n+1}|^2+\varphi (y_{n+1}) \le (n+1)|x-y_{n}|^2+\varphi (y_{n}) \\
n|x-y_{n}|^2+\varphi (y_{n}) \le n|x-y_{n+1}|^2+\varphi (y_{n+1}).
\end{cases}
$$
This implies $\varphi (y_{n}) \le \varphi (y_{n+1})$. We have
$$
n|x-y_n|^2+\varphi(y_n) \le n|x-y|^2+\varphi(y), \quad \forall y \in E.
$$

It follows that $\varphi(y_n) < +\infty$ and thus $y_n \in D(\varphi)$ for all $n$. Also,
$$
|x-y_n|^2 - |x-y|^2 \le \frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(y_n)}{n} \le \frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(y_1)}{n}, \quad \forall n \ge 1, \forall y \in E.
$$

This implies
$$
\lim_n |x-y_n|^2 - |x-y|^2 \le 0, \quad \forall y \in D(\varphi).
$$

Hence
$$
\lim_n |x-y_n|^2 \le |x-y|^2, \quad \forall y \in \overline{D(\varphi)}.
$$

This means $(y_n)$ is a minimizing sequence. By 2., we get $y_n \to Px$.